# Why is there only one critical value in the Wald confidence interval

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

Im currently studying the Wald test statistic for testing $ H_0: \boldsymbol{R'\hat{\beta}} = \boldsymbol{r} $ given by
$$
W = \frac{(\boldsymbol{R'\hat{\beta}} - \boldsymbol{r})'(\boldsymbol{R'(X'X)R)}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{R'\hat{\beta}} - \boldsymbol{r})}{\hat{\sigma}^2},
$$
where $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is a consistent estimator of $\sigma^2$. Now, under some assumptions, under the null:
$$
W \overset{\alpha}{\sim} \chi^2_q,
$$
where $q$ is the amount of restrictions imposed by $H_0$. Now my book says that the $(1-\alpha)$ confidence interval for $\boldsymbol{r}$ is given by
$$
[\boldsymbol{r} | W \leq c^*_{1-\alpha}].
$$
Now my questions is: why is there only one critical value for this confidence interval? I would think the confidence interval would be given by
$$
[\boldsymbol{r} | c^*_{\alpha/2} \leq W \leq c^*_{1-\alpha/2}].
$$
Does this have something to do with $W$ describing an ellipsoid?